# MySQL Trigger to prevent update in one table if particular data is available in another table

Tags: mysql, trigger, update, condition, dbatools

I need a MySQL trigger that can prevent update of a particular column data, if some specific data is available in another table.

I have two tables product and sales.

**Product**

[image]

**Sale**

[image]

I need to prevent the update of updated_at column in product table if the product_id is available in sale table.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what is your question?

Comment: I have tried using below trigger but it is not allowing me to update the product.updated_at  even if product is is not available in sale table.                                                                                                
                                                                                CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `product_BEFORE_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON `product` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF  EXISTS (SELECT product_id FROM testdb.sale where product_id is not null)
THEN
SET NEW.update_at = OLD.update_at;
ELSE
SET NEW.update_at = NEW.update_at;
END IF;
END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `product_BEFORE_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT 1 FROM sale WHERE product_id=NEW.product_id)=true) THEN
        set @message_text = concat('Product with id: ', NEW.product_id , ' exist on Sale table');
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @message_text;
    END IF;
END$$   
DELIMITER ;
```

Each time before update on the `product` table, the trigger will check if the `product_id` exist on the `sale` table and throw an error like:

> Query Error: Error: ER_SIGNAL_EXCEPTION: Product with id: x exist on
> Sale table

All below testing data can be found on the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5pbnyPrqGeg98c2Ti2FrFw/0)

```
create table product (
product_id int,
product_name varchar(15),
updated_at datetime ,
updated_by varchar(10) );

insert into product values 
(1,'tv','2020-07-22 00:00:00',null),
(2,'ac','2020-07-22 00:00:00',null),
(3,'cycle','2020-07-22 00:00:00',null),
(4,'car','2020-07-22 00:00:00',null),
(5,'cooler','2020-07-22 00:00:00',null);

create table sale (
sale_id int,
product_id int,
sale_price int,
created_at datetime ,
created_by varchar(10) );

insert into sale values 
(1,1,1000,null,null),
(2,2,1000,null,null),
(3,3,1000,null,null);

update product set updated_by ='Test' where product_id=1;
```

> Results
>
> ```
> Query Error: Error: ER_SIGNAL_EXCEPTION: Product with id: 1 exist on Sale table
> ```

Comment: That worked for me. If I need to check the product_id in more then one table.   For exmaple : two more tables are there one is  warehouse and another is WIP and both have product_id column. How to check in this situation.

Comment: @ ErgestBasha It is blocking me to update the full row, my purpose was to block the update of "updated_at"  field.